# Want to run thread in java database connectivity every 24 hours time interval

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, thread-sleep

This is the code I'm using to insert values taken from a local database to an online database. I am getting the data from a single local database and uploading each record in that to the 17 different tables online. The code is running successfully but at the end of 24 hours, the code automatically terminates with out running for the second time after the thread sleep time. I don't know why this happens. Please give me a solution to run the code for every 24 hours.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class online_data
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyThread1 thread1 = new MyThread1();
        thread1.start();
    }
}
class MyThread1 extends Thread
{

    public void run()
    {
        try{  
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

          //Connection1
          Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql124.main-hosting.eu/u678426119_kcg","u678426119_kcg","deepak"); 
          Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

          //Connection2
          Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/kcg","root","icdipl"); 
          Statement stmt2=conn.createStatement();
          int i = 1;
          String s = "online_data";

          while(true)
          {
            String s1 = s+i;
            //Date & Time
            Date dNow = new Date( );
            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd");
            SimpleDateFormat ft1 = new SimpleDateFormat ("hh:mm:ss");
            ResultSet rs=stmt2.executeQuery("select * from online_data");  
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String q="INSERT INTO "+s1+" VALUES ("+rs.getInt(1)+","+rs.getInt(2)+",'"+rs.getString(3)+"',"+rs.getFloat(4)+","+rs.getFloat(5)+","+rs.getFloat(6)+","+rs.getFloat(7)+","+rs.getFloat(8)+","+rs.getFloat(9)+","+rs.getFloat(10)+","+rs.getFloat(11)+","+rs.getFloat(12)+","+rs.getFloat(13)+","+rs.getFloat(14)+","+rs.getFloat(15)+","+rs.getFloat(16)+","+rs.getFloat(17)+","+rs.getFloat(18)+","+rs.getFloat(19)+","+rs.getFloat(20)+","+rs.getFloat(21)+","+rs.getFloat(22)+","+rs.getFloat(23)+",'"+rs.getString(24)+"',"+rs.getFloat(25)+",'"+rs.getString(26)+"',"+rs.getFloat(27)+",'"+rs.getString(28)+"',"+rs.getFloat(29)+","+rs.getFloat(30)+","+rs.getFloat(31)+","+rs.getFloat(32)+","+rs.getFloat(33)+","+rs.getFloat(34)+","+rs.getFloat(35)+",'"+rs.getString(36)+"',"+rs.getFloat(37)+",'"+rs.getString(38)+"','"+rs.getString(39)+"',"+rs.getFloat(40)+","+rs.getFloat(41)+","+rs.getFloat(42)+","+rs.getFloat(43)+","+rs.getFloat(44)+","+rs.getFloat(45)+","+rs.getFloat(46)+","+rs.getFloat(47)+","+rs.getFloat(48)+",'"+rs.getString(49)+"','"+rs.getString(50)+"',"+rs.getFloat(51)+","+rs.getFloat(52)+",'"+rs.getString(53)+"',"+rs.getFloat(54)+","+rs.getFloat(55)+","+rs.getFloat(56)+","+rs.getFloat(57)+","+rs.getFloat(58)+","+rs.getFloat(59)+","+rs.getFloat(60)+","+rs.getFloat(61)+","+rs.getFloat(62)+","+rs.getFloat(63)+","+rs.getFloat(64)+","+rs.getFloat(65)+","+rs.getFloat(66)+","+rs.getFloat(67)+","+rs.getFloat(68)+","+rs.getFloat(69)+","+rs.getFloat(70)+","+rs.getFloat(71)+","+rs.getFloat(72)+","+rs.getFloat(73)+","+rs.getFloat(74)+","+rs.getFloat(75)+","+rs.getFloat(76)+","+rs.getFloat(77)+","+rs.getFloat(78)+","+rs.getFloat(79)+","+rs.getFloat(80)+","+rs.getFloat(81)+","+rs.getFloat(82)+","+rs.getFloat(83)+","+rs.getFloat(84)+","+rs.getFloat(85)+","+rs.getFloat(86)+",'"+rs.getString(87)+"',"+rs.getFloat(88)+",'"+rs.getString(89)+"',"+rs.getFloat(90)+",'"+rs.getString(91)+"',"+rs.getFloat(92)+",'"+rs.getString(93)+"',"+rs.getFloat(94)+",'"+rs.getString(95)+"',"+rs.getFloat(96)+",'"+rs.getString(97)+"',"+rs.getFloat(98)+",'"+rs.getString(99)+"',"+rs.getFloat(100)+",'"+rs.getString(101)+"','"+ft.format(dNow)+"','"+ft1.format(dNow)+"')";
                stmt.executeUpdate(q);
                i+=1;
            }

            randomWait();
            i=1;
          }
          }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
    }


    void randomWait()
    {

        try {
           sleep((long)(1000*60*60*24));
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted!");
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you seriously just sleep for 24 *HOURS* with two **open** database connections?!? And on that note, you probably got a printed exception telling you *exactly* why your infinite loop terminated, and it probably involved an invalid connection...

Answer (score 1):

For starters, try moving your database connections into the while loop and closing them when you're done with them (ie before the thread goes to sleep).

Then, instead of doing all of this in a thread that sleeps for 24 hours, instead consider doing this inside a single static method, encapsulating a call to that in a [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) or something similar, and using a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or equivalent to schedule things.

Comment: Or schedule a cron job that runs every 24 hours

Comment: I mean I just tried to answer the question. But yeah, I feel like this is really **The Wrong Way™**.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the connection inside the "while (true)", and closing the connection at the end of this while loop. This way, your connection will be opened every 24 hours, then do the select/insert and then the connection would then close immediately after doing all the database operations.

If you want the program to not terminate during a database operation failure (when an exception is raised), and try the select/insert again after 24 hours of failure - you would need an inner try/catch/finally block to catch and log/ignore the exception. Ideally the close connection should be done in a finally block (in inside try/catch/finally block) - to close the connection in either case - whether the database operations are successful or not.